# A term for a animation style used in anime

Tags: anime

I'm watching some anime on netflix.  Is there a term for when the characters get real emotional they are suddenly animated as cutesy almost childlike versions of themselves? Then they go right back? Here's a clip I just recorded from an albeit terrible show Sekirei

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the term you're looking for is [Chibi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chibi_%28term%29)

> Chibi (ちび or チビ) is a Japanese slang word meaning "short person" or "small child".
>
> Chibi style is usually used in depicting scenes which are cute and/or humorous, and it is extremely rare for it to be used for an entire anime series. It is quite popular in manga, however.

Comment: Someone feel free to clean that up. The mobile app doesnt make for easy editing.

Comment: That seems like it

Comment: Awesome. Without a picture to really see what you're referring to I'm just sort of taking a stab in the dark.

Comment: Uploaded a example clip

Comment: after viewing the clip do you still believe it is Chibi?

Comment: It's not quite the chibi style I would have expected, but it seems fairly similar. My only hesitation is that they don't deform her entire body, just her face.